# PHP How can I get full image url by useing preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-match-all

for example

```
$string = 
'aaaaaaasssssshttp://www.1.com/images/001/001/001/1.jpgddwxeaaaaaa
crewcwehttp://www.2.com/images/002/002/002/2.jpgrcegcger
cgwcgrewhttp://www.3.com/images/003/003/003/3.jpgcgergcer
cerggewrcgrewhttp://www.4.com/images/004/004/004/4.jpgecgewrcgerwcg
cerghttp://www.5.com/images/005/005/005/5.jpg';
```

I want to get the first image full url form this stiring like :

```
"http://www.1.com/images/001/001/001/1.jpg"
```

I use this function but it does not work

```
 if (preg_match_all('^http:\/\/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)$/i', $string, $matches))

 print_r ($matches[1]);
```

Who can help me ? thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the following code, and it works. It only captures jpg-urls.

```
$string = 
'aaaaaaasssssshttp://www.1.com/images/001/001/001/1.jpgddwxeaaaaaa
crewcwehttp://www.2.com/images/002/002/002/2.jpgrcegcger
cgwcgrewhttp://www.3.com/images/003/003/003/3.jpgcgergcer
cerggewrcgrewhttp://www.4.com/images/004/004/004/4.jpgecgewrcgerwcg
cerghttp://www.5.com/images/005/005/005/5.jpg';

preg_match_all("((http|https|ftp|ftps)://?([a-zA-Z0-9\\\./]*.jpg))", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0][0]);
```